# Database reference causes warning in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

In our Sql Server 2008 database project we reference some outside .dbSchema files. When I try to build the database project using MSBuild, I get a weird warning (We are using TFS 2010 for our build server if that makes a difference):

*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets (1777): An error occurred when opening a file "file.dbschema": Assembly "file.dbschema" is not a valid .NET assembly and will be skipped for analysis.**

Any idea whats going on, and how I get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have [Test Impact Analysis](http://intovsts.net/2009/02/05/test-impact-analysis/) enabled?  If you do, it would appear that TFS Build is scanning your code, encountering this file, and letting you know that it is being skipped because it cannot recognize it.  Another user encountered a [similar issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/cc3bfda4-21f3-4f9c-b8e6-4a26e89d5882) and a [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573739/team-build-test-impact-analysis-warnings-when-solution-contains-a-windows-azure-cloud-service-project) was created.

Comment: Yup, sounds like its related to Test Impact Analysis. I posted a question on that MSDN thread to ask how to turn it off. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It appears that the same thing is happening in my database project(s).  I added a vote to both of these and comments to the MSDN Connect ticket.